# Enable/disable RTL Support on run-time

Tags: android, android-layout, right-to-left

I want to programmatically change layouting direction on run-time using Java, instead of relying on the static boolean `supportsRTL` XML property on compile-time.

Any idea on how to achieve real-time RTL-LTR switching?

Answer (score 2):

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR);
```